# Why is this React Router redirect not working? How to make it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

Why is the following React Router redirect not working? How can I make it work?

```
 <div>
                <Route path = "/" exact component = {Slideshow} /> 
                <Route path = "/favourite-movies/1"  exact component = {TopMovies} /> 
                <Redirect from = "/film/abc/:id" to ="/film/:id" />
                <Route path = "/film/:id" exact component = {Film} />
          </div>
```

Let me elucidate my intention. The favourite movies section contains some elements which link to /film/:id, (dynamically). Say id = 100. In film/100 page , I have a list of recommended movies, which in turn also links to /film/:id. When I am directly calling say film/50 from film/100 page, even though the url changes to film/50, the content remains the same. Then I refresh the page which results in the contents of film/50 being rendered.

To prevent this I am calling film/abc/50 from film/100. I want to redirect the film/abc/50 page to film/50 page. Is this a feasible solution of the problem? How can I solve this problem? Please clarify.

Comment: I think we need further info. Can you show us how you build the links, and the content of your Film component?

Comment: Tried without the "exact" for "/film/:id" ?

Answer (score 0):

Each `Route` in React-Router must be child of `Switch` or `Router`.
Do you have your `Route` in `Switch` or `Router` component placed?